# Insert "uuid" in "users" table

Tags: database, entities

I am building a web-service which will register user for my drupal site from android device. For Registration I am inserting data in the 'users' table of Drupal database.
But the problem occurs with the "uuid" column in the "users" table.I don't know using which logic I can insert data in 'uuid' column while registraion. Please help me.

Comment: Note that the column in the `users` table is `uid`, not `uuid`. If you didn't just make a typo in this question, and you're using `uuid` in your code, take away one of the "u"s.

Comment: If it's the _uid_ column, that is auto-incremental. To have a unique value across different sites, you need to use the UUID module, I guess.

Comment: NO.I didnot make any typo.I am using "Droupon" theme which has a field in 'users' table ,named 'uuid'.It also has 'uid' on the table.But I want to insert 'uuid' as it is generating on user registration.